# Installing memcached on OS X to use with django (python)

Tags: python, django, memcached, makefile, installation

Hay, i was wondering if anyone can point me to a a tutorial on installing memcached to be used with django on OS X (grabbing source, making, installing, installing anything else i'll need to use it).

any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memcached server package: http://memcached.darwinports.com/

Python memcached client package: http://py-memcached.darwinports.com/

Comment: I haven't got darwinports installed, have you got a tutorial on how to install that ;)

Comment: Does this install the "python-memcached" library?

Answer (score 9):

Try using homebrew instead of darwinports. It is very easy to use, and I installed memcached using it. Then it is just:

```
brew install memcached
```

Works great with sudo, as long as you haven't used sudo to install anything to wherever you installed homebrew.

Comment: I had problems with brew on Lion, but this worked: sudo easy_install python-memcached

Comment: What problems, PhoebeB? I've been running Lion since it came out, including a brand new machine today. I had to change permissions on /Library/Python/*, which was explained in the brew docs.

Answer (score 2):

four simply steps:

1) `brew install memcached`

2) `pip install python-memcached`

3) `brew services start memcached`

4) django setup:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use brew too with

```
brew install memcached
```

You can read about homebrew here:
[Link](https://brew.sh/)